# Почему не срабатывает регулярное выражение?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Для данной строки `../img/egor/slider-photo.png` пытаюсь найти подстроку `../img/`
с помощью регулярного выражения `/\.\./.*?//`, но работать отказывается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не работает, потому что `/` необходимо экранировать, как и `.`.

```
/\.\.\/.*?\//
```

Comment: Уже разобрался. спасибо